# Can the word 'consequences' be used in the meaning of 'punishment'?

Tags: word-meaning

Assume that X has committed some misdeeds. Would it be correct to say: "I asked X to leave and never return. If he refuses then I will see to it that he faces the consequences"? (meaning: if X does not leave, then X will be prosecuted and punished for his past misdeeds)

Intuitively, I would be inclined to believe that the above sentence is correct. However, this may be just my mother tongue bleeding into my English.

If 'consequences' cannot be used in the meaning of 'punishment', then the above sentence makes no sense. The ultimatum to leave or be punished is the consequence of X's misdeeds. Therefore, the saying that "X must leave or face consequences" seems circular: it expands to "X must leave or face the alternative between leaving or facing the alternative between leaving or ...".

Comment: The ultimatum isn't the consequence.  The result of misdeeds is likely to be some kind of retribution, so in this context 'the consequences' _implies_ (but doesn't _mean_) punishment.

Comment: @KateBunting why is the ultimatum not the consequence? Wasn't it made as a result of misdeeds?

Comment: Well, obviously the ultimatum wouldn't be necessary if the person hadn't committed the misdeeds, but I meant that the consequences _referred to_ in the ultimatum are the result of the misdeeds, not of failing to leave.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "consequences" can be used for punishment. I suppose there is a difference between the natural results of some action and man-made results. Like there's a difference between, "If you don't eat enough foods with vitamin C, you will get scurvy", and, "If you don't clean your room, I'm taking away your video game machine." One is a natural, inevitable result. The other is something that a person does. But in English, both are referred to as "consequences". From the point of view of the person suffering the consequences, whether they are dealt out by nature or by a human being may not matter much. If your arm is broken because you fell down the stairs, or if your arm is broken because Guido beat you up for not repaying the loan shark, either way, your arm is broken.

Comment: I would probably say 'I will make sure that _there will be_ consequences [for him]' if I were planning a punishment for him.

Answer (score 1):

**consequences** is a catch-all term to refer to what will ensue from some action or choice.  How the word is understood is determined by its context. Sometimes the implications will be clear, sometimes not.

> I wouldn't go walking out on that thin ice on the river. The current is strong. If you fall through, the consequences could be dire.
>
> You said yes when he asked you to the dance and now you have to live with the consequences.

In the first example,  the potential for drowning is quite clear. In the second example, who knows what the consequences might be without further context? Perhaps he's a terribly clumsy dancer -- or a very skilled one who shows off? The only clear thing is that the person who is going to be his date is going to find the experience unpleasant in some way, at least according to the speaker's sense of things.

In your description, the speaker could  be threatening violence or threatening to call the police or threatening a law suit or threatening to let the air out of his tires. All that one knows is that it is a threat of some kind.